# knit to pdf in emacs using polymode

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, ess, rnw

I am trying to knit my `Rnw` file into PDF. With `ess-noweb` mode, I could knit and view the pdf but with `polymode`, I could knit to tex with name filename[woven].tex but could not view the pdf. Do I need to open the tex file again and compile it or is there any direct way?

Answer (score 2):

Use `M-n-e` to export Rnw to PDF in `polymode`. It will take care of both weaving and latexing, and opens up the PDF for you.

Comment: when doing this I run into an error that explains that: 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.